# How to capture 3 points from user and form a triangle?

Tags: python, python-3.x

How to write a program that takes inputs from user as the coordinates of three mouse clicks and then draws a triangle in the graphics window using those three points? What are the modules for graphics to use for this purpose?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), look around, and read through the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) If you run into a specific problem, research it thoroughly, search thoroughly here, and if you're still stuck post your code and a description of the problem. Also, remember to include [Minimum, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). People will be glad to help

Answer (score 0):

This draws triangle every time you click the canvas three times.

```
from tkinter import *

#to store triangle coordinates
coordinates = []
root = Tk()


#called everytime the canvas is clicked
def pressed(event):
    global coordinates
    coordinates.append((event.x, event.y))

    if len(coordinates) == 3:
        for x in range(3):
            secondCordinate = (x + 1) % 3
            canvas.create_line(coordinates[x][0], coordinates[x][1], coordinates[secondCordinate][0], coordinates[secondCordinate][1])
        coordinates = []


canvas= Canvas(root, width=400, height=400)
canvas.bind("<Button-1>", pressed)
canvas.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Accept it? how do I do that?